# Good tutorials / resources for PAB (testnet)

Tags: plutus, testnet, pab, plutus-pab, documentation

Does anyone have good resources on the PAB connecting to the testnet? I know Lars Brünjes explained it in the pioneers program, but, at that time, we still had to rely on the emulator.

I also know we have plutus-apps (with Nami demo) and plutus-starter, which are good resources, but there are not a lot of explanations of what each thing does.

Any videos, blog posts or even well-documented repositories would be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [***Plutus starter PAB testnet***](https://github.com/invictusappscom/plutus-starter-pab-testnet) notes and [***Hosted PAB setup for Alonzo testnet***](https://gist.github.com/mikekeke) gist.